# Problems with merging on-disk tables with millions of rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

> TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [date] because its data
>   contents are [empty] object dtype.

Hello SO! Currently have got two large HDFStore containing each one node, both the nodes doesn't fit in memory. The nodes don't contain NaN values. Now I would like to merge these two nodes using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614512/merging-two-tables-with-millions-of-rows-in-python/14617925#14617925). First tested for a small store where all the data fits in one chunk and this was working OK. But now for the case where it has to merge chunk by chunk and it's giving me the following error: `TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [date], because its data contents are [empty] object dtype`.

This is the code that I'm running.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pandas import HDFStore
>>> print pd.__version__
0.12.0rc1

>>> h5_1 ='I:/Data/output/test8\\var1.h5'
>>> h5_3 ='I:/Data/output/test8\\var3.h5'
>>> h5_1temp = h5_1.replace('.h5','temp.h5')

>>> A = HDFStore(h5_1)
>>> B = HDFStore(h5_3)
>>> Atemp = HDFStore(h5_1temp)

>>> print A
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: I:/Data/output/test8\var1.h5
/var1            frame_table  (shape->12626172)
>>> print B
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: I:/Data/output/test8\var3.h5
/var3            frame_table  (shape->6313086)

>>> nrows_a = A.get_storer('var1').nrows
>>> nrows_b = B.get_storer('var3').nrows
>>> a_chunk_size = 500000
>>> b_chunk_size = 500000
>>> for a in xrange(int(nrows_a / a_chunk_size) + 1):
...     a_start_i = a * a_chunk_size
...     a_stop_i  = min((a + 1) * a_chunk_size, nrows_a)
...     a = A.select('var1', start = a_start_i, stop = a_stop_i)
...     for b in xrange(int(nrows_b / b_chunk_size) + 1):
...         b_start_i = b * b_chunk_size
...         b_stop_i = min((b + 1) * b_chunk_size, nrows_b)
...         b = B.select('var3', start = b_start_i, stop = b_stop_i)
...         Atemp.append('mergev13', pd.merge(a, b , left_index=True, right_index=True,how='inner'))

... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 658, in append
    self._write_to_group(key, value, table=True, append=True, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 923, in _write_to_group
    s.write(obj = value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3251, in write
    return super(AppendableMultiFrameTable, self).write(obj=obj.reset_index(), data_columns=data_columns, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 2983, in write
    **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 2715, in create_axes
    raise e
TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [date] because
its data contents are [empty] object dtype
```

Things that I noticed, it mentions that I'm on pandas_version:= '0.10.1', however my pandas version is 0.12.0rc1. Further more some more specific information of the nodes:

```
>>> A.select_column('var1','date').unique()
array([2006001, 2006009, 2006017, 2006025, 2006033, 2006041, 2006049,
       2006057, 2006065, 2006073, 2006081, 2006089, 2006097, 2006105,
       2006113, 2006121, 2006129, 2006137, 2006145, 2006153, 2006161,
       2006169, 2006177, 2006185, 2006193, 2006201, 2006209, 2006217,
       2006225, 2006233, 2006241, 2006249, 2006257, 2006265, 2006273,
       2006281, 2006289, 2006297, 2006305, 2006313, 2006321, 2006329,
       2006337, 2006345, 2006353, 2006361], dtype=int64)

>>> B.select_column('var3','date').unique()
array([2006001, 2006017, 2006033, 2006049, 2006065, 2006081, 2006097,
       2006113, 2006129, 2006145, 2006161, 2006177, 2006193, 2006209,
       2006225, 2006241, 2006257, 2006273, 2006289, 2006305, 2006321,
       2006337, 2006353], dtype=int64)

>>> A.get_storer('var1').levels
['x', 'y', 'date']

>>> A.get_storer('var1').attrs
/var1._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 12 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := ['date', 'y', 'x'],
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    levels := ['x', 'y', 'date'],
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['x', 'y', 'date', 'var1'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_multiframe',
    values_cols := ['values_block_0', 'date', 'y', 'x']]

>>> A.get_storer('var1').table
/var1/table (Table(12626172,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "date": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "y": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3),
  "x": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=4)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (3276,)
  autoIndex := True
  colindexes := {
    "date": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "y": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "x": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False}

>>> B.get_storer('var3').levels
['x', 'y', 'date']

>>> B.get_storer('var3').attrs
/var3._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 12 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := ['date', 'y', 'x'],
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    levels := ['x', 'y', 'date'],
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['x', 'y', 'date', 'var3'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_multiframe',
    values_cols := ['values_block_0', 'date', 'y', 'x']]

>>> B.get_storer('var3').table
/var3/table (Table(6313086,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "date": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "y": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3),
  "x": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=4)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (3276,)
  autoIndex := True
  colindexes := {
    "date": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "y": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "x": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False}

>>> print Atemp
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: I:/Data/output/test8\var1temp.h5
/mergev13            frame_table  (shape->823446)
```

Since chunksize is 500000 and shape of node in Atemp is 823446, gives me that at least one chunk is merged. But I cannot figure out where the error is coming from and I also run out of clues trying to discover where it's exactly going wrong. Any help is very much appreciated..

**EDIT**

By reducing the chunksize of my test store it gives the same error. Of course not good, but now gives me possibility to share. Click [here](https://files.myopera.com/m.vanhoek/files/data.zip) for the code + HDFStores.

Comment: the ``pandas_version`` refers to how the meta data is saved ; this hasn't changed in a while. i'll take a look in a few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merged frame possibly will have no rows. Appending a len-zero frame is an error (though should be more imformative).

Check the len before appending

```
df = pd.merge(a, b , left_index=True, right_index=True,how='inner')

if len(df):
    Atemp.append('mergev46', df)
```

Results with your provided dataset

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: var4.h5
/var4            frame_table  (shape->1334)
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: var6.h5
/var6            frame_table  (shape->667)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 1334 entries, (928, 310, 2006001) to (1000, 238, 2006361)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
var4    1334  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 667 entries, (928, 310, 2006001) to (1000, 238, 2006353)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
var6    667  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: var4temp.h5
/mergev46            frame_table  (shape->977)
```

You should close the files FYI when you are done with them

```
Closing remaining open files: var6.h5... done var4.h5... done var4temp.h5... done
```

Comment: I added an issue about this, I think there is a subtle error here unrelated to HDFStore that is raising an error (rather than just letting it proceed, which I think is correct), an empty frame will normally succeed on the append, except in the case you had (and I illustrate): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4273

Comment: Clear example as you've given on github. Very impressive how you manage to discover the underlying problems when errors are raised. Will have time this evening to check on my datasets. One little thing that I notice from the results you provide: how come can the node 'mergev46' have a larger shape than 'var6' by doing an 'inner' merge?

Comment: when you open the temp store (the one you are appendin), open in ``mode='w'``, otherwise you will be appending to a previous run of your code

Comment: Just to let you know, it's running nicely on my dataset. But I've to be patient with store of 13.5gig

Comment: great! you should try using different chunksizes (100k seems to be a nice round number usually), and your problem actually is parallizeable (though remember to write to SEPARATE stores, PyTables is thread/processor-safe ONLY FOR READING!) and then combine after

Comment: Using 100k as chunksize. I've been looking into parallel execution of my code for a longer period already, but always get stuck. First of all, which python library would you recommend to use for this?