# python - simple way to join 2 arrays/lists based on common values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried for a while but can't find a simple way to join 2 lists or arrays based only on common values. Similar to an SQL inner join but with arrays/lists and not dict, or some other data type. eg.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
join(a, b)
```

prints

```
[2, 3]
```

seems so simple but lacking from python or numpy.

Comment: You need intersection of the lists?

Comment: [numpy.intersect1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Probably a duplicate, but in case it is not:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [2,3,4]
>>> list(set(a) & set(b))
[2, 3]
```

For large lists (external data), see [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614512/merging-two-tables-with-millions-of-rows-in-python).

Comment: I am not familiar with the Binary AND Operator being used with set()s. In this scenario, is the & Operator operating on the bits of each of the element within the two sets, or is it operating on the element (as a whole) of the two sets?

Comment: For sets, `&` performs set intersection, returning a new set containing all the elements that are in both `a` and `b`. It has nothing to do with bits. If the `&` operator is used between two `int` operands then it will perform a bitwise AND. In Python you can create your own classes and make the operators do pretty much anything you want. This is generally considered a good thing when used properly. By the way, the Python `set` class makes the `|` do union, and the `^` do disjoint union, and `-` do set subtraction.

Comment: Thank you for the responding!

Answer (score 11):

If you need to keep the list in the same order as in `a`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
c = [x for x in a if x in b]
```

if the order is not important, use Ray answers, that should be faster, but not guaranteed to keep the list order the same as the order of the elements in `a`.